# Trying to decode HTTP Response in python. Can't figure out JSON decoding

Tags: python, json, encoding, utf-8, gzip

Here's the basic request:

```
req = urllib2.Request(f"https://www.voter.ie/api/search/name/{name}/surname/{surname}/eircode/{eircode}/lang/en")

req.add_header("Connection", "keep-alive")
req.add_header("Accept", "application/json, text/plain, */*")
req.add_header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36 OPR/62.0.3331.99")
req.add_header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br")
req.add_header("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9")

response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

Here are the headers, I can see that it's JSON in `Content-Type` and encoding is `utf-8`:

```
response.getheaders()

[('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked'),
 ('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8'),
 ('Content-Encoding', 'gzip'),
 ('Vary', 'Accept-Encoding'),
 ('Server', 'Kestrel'),
 ('Request-Context', 'appId=cid-v1:25017a8d-4490-471a-a8d0-e9e17860f987'),
 ('Strict-Transport-Security', 'max-age=2592000'),
 ('X-Content-Type-Options', 'nosniff'),
 ('Referrer-Policy', 'no-referrer'),
 ('X-XSS-Protection', '1; mode=block'),
 ('X-Frame-Options', 'Deny'),
 ('X-Powered-By', 'ASP.NET'),
 ('Date', 'Fri, 02 Aug 2019 14:45:33 GMT'),
 ('Connection', 'close')]
```

So when I try to read it or decode it I am getting many errors, but first of all this is what it looks like. I haven't posted the full string as it's too long, but this is a sample:

```
response.read()

b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\xed\xbd\x07`\x1cI\x96%&/m\xca{\x7fJ\xf5J\xd7\xe0t\xa1\x08\x80`\x13$\xd8\x90@\x10\xec\xc1\x88\xcd\xe6\x92\xec\x1diG#)\xab*\x81\xcaeVe]f\x16@\xcc\xed\x9d\xbc\xf7\xde{\xef\xbd\xf7\xde{\xef\xbd\xf7\xba;\x9dN\'\xf7\xdf\xff?\\fd\x01l\xf6\xceJ\xda\xc9\x9e!\x80\xa
```

What I've tried using methods I've found on here StackOverflow:

```
response.read().decode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte


raw_data = response.read()
json.loads(raw_data.decode('utf-8'))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte


string = response.read().decode('utf-8')
json_obj = json.loads(string)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the response headers hint, the data has been compressed with gzip.  You need to decompress it before doing anything else.

```
import gzip, json
gz = response.read()
j = gzip.decompress(gz)
data = json.loads(j.decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you very much. Haven't come across compressed responses before. Now I know.

Comment: receive an error AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'decompress'

Comment: @Patlatus `gzip.decompress` was added in Python 3.2, so if you are using an earlier Python you'll need to use the tools available in that version (I don't have time to investigate right now I'm afraid).